# Convert an `int` to a C string with size limitation

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel

Creating a textual version of an `int` to save as a C string to a buffer that is all ready allocated and maximum allowable size is determined seems common.  Thought I'd make a function to fulfill that.

If the destination size is too small or destination is `NULL`, return `NULL`.

Your critique of functionality, style, use, etc. is requested.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

char *int_strnull(int x, char *dest, size_t dest_size) {
  if (dest != NULL) {
    // Size local buffer to x needs.  Note 10/33 just greater than log(2)
    char buf[sizeof x * CHAR_BIT * 10 / 33 + 3];
    char *p = &buf[sizeof buf - 1];
    // Work with negative absolute value to cope with INT_MIN
    int xna = x < 0 ? x : -x;

    // Form string
    *p = '\0';
    do {
      *--p = '0' - xna % 10;
      xna /= 10;
    } while (xna);
    if (x < 0) {
      *--p = '-';
    }

    // Copy string
    size_t src_size = &buf[sizeof buf] - p;
    if (src_size > dest_size) {
      // Not enough room
      return NULL;
    }
    memcpy(dest, p, src_size);
  }
  return dest;
}
```

Similar to `snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", some_int);` but without the `printf()` overhead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use some constants**:

This `char buf[sizeof x * CHAR_BIT * 10 / 33 + 3];`

Would be a lot better if written like this: `char buf[MAX_CONV_CHARS];` (or any other name your might prefer for the constant).

Also, do you really care about being that exact with the size of `buf`? I usually just throw some large number that can't overflow, like `128`.

**Return early**:

Instead of nesting the entire function under an `if`, return early:

```
char *int_strnull(int x, char *dest, size_t dest_size) {

    if ((dest == NULL) || (dest_size < MIN_SIZE)) {
        return NULL;
    }
```

**Mind your naming**:

`xna` is an abbreviation for what exactly? Not obvious to me. `x` is also very vague. Call it `input`, `number` or even `value`.

`int_strnull()` also seems odd. Why not just `int_to_string()`?

**Local buffer actually needed?**

Finally, I don't really get the necessity of the local buffer `buf`. Why not simply write to `dest` directly. That would also save a `memcpy` at the end. I guess you did that to first figure out the total length of the string. But since it is such a small string, I would suggest just requiring that the output buffer be at least the maximum size.

Comment: 1) Using a define or constant vs. `sizeof x * CHAR_BIT * 10 / 33 + 3` is a good idea.  2) Coding in embedded programs would rarely tolerate arbitrary size buffers like 128, especially when right-sized ones can be had.  2) `strnull` as part of a variable name is an attempt to convey that the function handles a C string _or_ `NULL`. `int_to_string()` would not imply handling or generation of `NULL` pointers. 4) By not requiring a buffer size for the widest possible `int`, the calling routine may know it is using reduced range of `int` and is offering a reduced size the takes advantage of that.

Comment: 5) `xna` is indeed a weak name. 6) Local buffer helps with creating an answer in a location known not to overflow as well as allow creation is the least to most significant digit order. - which simplifies coding vs. schemes that generate the other direction.

Comment: @chux, Okay :-)

Comment: @chux  But it doesn't handle NULL.  On NULL, it simply returns NULL.  Since it also returns NULL if the string doesn't fit into the dest, I would regard NULL as an error result.  If it really handled NULL, I'd expect it to allocate memory with calloc or malloc and return the result.  You wouldn't name a function foo_successerror would you?  Compare to malloc, which also returns NULL on failure.  Null does not appear in the malloc name.  You have to look it up to know that that is a possible result.

Comment: @Brythan the function handles `NULL` input in a trivial manner, but unlike `strcpy()` or `sprintf()`, it does not result in undefined behavior.  `NULL` _is_ an indication of error,   Allocating memory with a `NULL` buffer input is a an interesting idea, hmmm.  An alternate function name suggestion would be appreciated.  This routine is core to a number of routines that handle C strings and `NULL` as legal inputs and outputs, `NULL` being use to indicate error. and possible passing through a number of functions, much like NaN does with floating point.

Comment: My two cents in the matter: I think this `NULL` handling behavior would be best described in the documentation, as trying to aggregate that info to the name is liable to hurt readability by producing awkward names. But the end choice is ultimately up to you.

Comment: Especially like the ideas about `MAX_CONV_CHARS`, "Return early" and "Mind your naming".